# Calculating correlation coefficient efficiently

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have this huge dimensional data.

One A of size (50,12000) and B of size (50,1000).

I want to calculate the correlation of the each column of A with each column of B. How to do this efficiently

I tried with `corr([A B])` in matlab but it consumes lots of memory and freezes. How to do this quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Check [Luis's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20859421/2180721): 12000 * 1000 * 8 bytes is 92 Mb only.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the correlation of the each column of `A` with each column of `B` you use `corr(A,B)`, not `corr([A B])`.

If `corr(A,B)` causes memory problems, work in chunks. For example, the following code divides `A` into vertical stripes of `chunk_size` columns, computes the correlation of each `A`-stripe with `B`, and stores it. The final result is the same as `corr(A,B)`.

```
chunk_size = 100; %// must divide size(A,2) (easy to avoid if needed, though)
result = NaN(size(A,2),size(B,2)); %// preallocate
for ii = chunk_size:chunk_size:size(A,2)
    ind = ii+(-chunk_size+1:0);
    result(ind,:) = corr(A(:,ind),B);
end
```